# CSS Header Alignment

Tags: html, css, html-table

I just can't seem to get my header to line up correctly. I'm the closest I can get in internet explorer with the below code but it looks terrible in Firefox. I've tried everything I could read on every forum and the more I play with it, it only looks worse. All I want is header.png to spread across the page and that works fine. Then I want a centered header with formtop.png as background and that works fine. Now inside that header I want logo.png to be to the bottom left of the header div and my fireworks menu table to be to the bottom right. In IE everything lines up except the menu table has some space between itself and the very bottom of the div. In Firefox nothing lines up at all. I suspect because of the absolute and relative settings. Everything I want inside my header div ends up at the top left in Firefox. But playing with the absolute and relative attributes blows everything up in IE. Can someone help or point me to a basic tutorial that shows how to line up a header div that applies to most browsers?

```
</head>
    <body style="text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0;">
    <div  style="width:100%; height:100px; background-image:url(header.png);position:relative;">
      <div>
        <div style="height:100%; width:100%; background-image:url(formtop.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center; left:0; bottom:0; position: absolute;">
          <div style="width:920px; position:relative;">
            <div><img name="n12" src="logo.png" border="0" alt="" align="left"></div>
            <div style="padding-top:10px; float:right; padding-right:30px; position:absolute; bottom:0;">
              <table style="display: inline-table;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="400">
                <!-- fwtable fwsrc="Untitled" fwpage="Page 1" fwbase="navbar.png" fwstyle="Dreamweaver" fwdocid = "1979268284" fwnested="0" -->
                <tr>
                  <td><img src="images/NavBar/spacer.gif" width="124" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
                  <td><img src="images/NavBar/spacer.gif" width="139" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
                  <td><img src="images/NavBar/spacer.gif" width="137" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
                  <td><img src="images/NavBar/spacer.gif" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><img name="navbar_r1_c1_s1" src="images/NavBar/navbar_r1_c1_s1.png" width="124" height="50" border="0" id="navbar_r1_c1_s1" alt="" /></td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:;" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('navbar_r1_c2_s1','','images/NavBar/navbar_r1_c2_s2.png',1);"><img name="navbar_r1_c2_s1" src="images/NavBar/navbar_r1_c2_s1.png" width="139" height="50" border="0" id="navbar_r1_c2_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
                  <td><a href="javascript:;" onMouseOut="MM_swapImgRestore();" onMouseOver="MM_swapImage('navbar_r1_c3_s1','','images/NavBar/navbar_r1_c3_s3.png',1);"><img name="navbar_r1_c3_s1" src="images/NavBar/navbar_r1_c3_s1.png" width="137" height="50" border="0" id="navbar_r1_c3_s1" alt="" /></a></td>
                  <td><img src="images/NavBar/spacer.gif" width="1" height="50" border="0" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
            <br/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a published site we can look at?

Comment: Almost in 2012... Inline styles... pain in the ***. Just a little style.css can bring a wide smile on any programmer's face

Comment: You really should clean up the markup. If you write your HTML the right way, the CSS will be a lot easier.

Comment: Probably because Im a newb it seems easier for me to make adjustments inline and then add everything to the stylesheet after. I'll try not to do it inline. Everything is on localhost right now. If I can't fix it I'll throw it online to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even more concise:

```
margin: 0px auto;
```

It would be very helpful to see a published site, though, as nmagerko said.

Comment: Its not perfect yet but you have me on the right track. Definitely what i was looking for. Thanks! I have everything line up horizontally the way I want but in firefox how do I get a div to the bottom of the containing div? Ive tried bottom:0; margin-bottom:0 and it just won't move in firefox.

Comment: Depends on how you have it positioned. It can be a little tricky like in the case of a "sticky" footer, but there are some good tutorials out there (see http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ or http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/ for some help there). Which div are you trying to position at the bottom of its containing div?

PS: Love the screenshots of the page. Looks good!

Comment: That second suggestion did the trick. Thanks so much! Can't believe such a simple thing is so complicated.

Comment: No worries. Good luck and happy coding! I hope the project turns out well.

Answer (score 0):

To center align  in  in forefox use `margin` in addition to `text-align: center`

Something like:

```
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
```